# NUL character and static character arrays/string literals in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I understand that strings are terminated by a NUL `'\0'` byte in C.
However, what I can't figure out is why a `0` in a string literal acts differently than a `0` in an char array created on the stack. When checking for NUL terminators in a literal, the zeros in the middle of the array are not treated as such.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{

    /* here, one would expect strlen to evaluate to 2 */
    char *confusion = "11001";
    size_t len = strlen(confusion);
    printf("length = %zu\n", len); /* why is this == 5, as opposed to 2? */



    /* why is the entire segment printed here, instead of the first two bytes?*/
    char *p = confusion;
    while (*p != '\0')
        putchar(*p++);
    putchar('\n');



    /* this evaluates to true ... OK */
    if ((char)0 == '\0')
        printf("is null\n");


    /* and if we do this ... */
    char s[6];
    s[0] = 1;
    s[1] = 1;
    s[2] = 0;
    s[3] = 0;
    s[4] = 1;
    s[5] = '\0';

    len = strlen(s); /* len == 2, as expected. */
    printf("length = %zu\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 length = 5
 11001
 is null
 length = 2
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: A string literal **is** a `char` array! And there is no stack in the C language. And a pointer is not an array. "here, one would expect strlen to evaluate to 2" - Why? Looks as if there are some missconceptions about arrays, pointers and strings.

Comment: Because '0' != 0

Comment: The character `'0'` has a value of 48 ([usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)). The null terminator `'\0'` has a value of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'confusion' is a pointer to char of a literal string.
So the memory looks something like

```
 [11001\0]
```

So when you print the variable 'confusion', it will print everything until first null character which is represented by \0.
Zeroes in 11001 are not null, they are literal zeroes since it is surrounded with double quotes.

However, in your char array assignment for variable 's', you are assigning a decimal value 0 to 
char variable.  When you do that, ASCII decimal value of 0 which is ASCII character value of NULL character gets assigned to it.  So the the character array looks something like in the memory

```
  [happyface, happyface, NULL]
```

ASCII character happyface has ASCII decimal value of 1.
So when you print, it will print everything up to first NULL and thus
the strlen is 2.

The trick here is understanding what really gets assigned to a character variable when a decimal value is assigned to it.

Try this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int
 main(void)
{
    char c = 0;

    printf( "%c\n", c );  //Prints the ASCII character which is NULL.
    printf( "%d\n", c );  //Prints the decimal value.

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

'0' and 0 are not the same value. (The first one is 48, usually, although technically the precise value is implementation-defined and it is considered very bad style to write 48 to refer to the character '0'.)

If a '0' terminated a character string, you wouldn't be able to put zeros in strings, which would be a bit... limiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can view an ASCII Table (e.g. http://www.asciitable.com/) to check the exact value of character '0' and null